# How to format input text from a texarea into mysql and than display it the same way

Tags: mysql, text, input

Hi I am using the following code to insdert data into mysql table:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO DB (spanish, english)
VALUES
('$_POST[spanish]','$_POST[english]')";
```

than here is the input form:

```
 <form action="insert.php" method="post">
  <p>bulgarian text:</p>
  <p>
  <textarea type="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" name="bulgarian"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
  english text:</p>
  <p>
    <textarea type="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" name="english"></textarea>
</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

and this is the display procedure:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<td>" . $row['english'] . "</td>";
}
```

my problem now is once I put the text inside the database , and than once I display it it is displayed without any formatting. I would like to know how to make it to be displayed the way it is entered inside the text area with all the formatting and the new lines

thanks.

Comment: **Immediately stop using this code**. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and [`mysql_` functions are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data put into a `<textarea>` is in plain text. When you put that data in a HTML-formatted page, the browser will ["collapse"](http://www.maproom.co.uk/invis1.htm) the whitespace.

There are two options:

1. Surround your date with `<pre>` and `</pre>`, so the formatting
   stays intact.
2. Use a function like [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to create (rudimentary) HTML.

Comment: surround it where exactly ? in which code part ? with the pre tags

Comment: Around the unformatted data you want to show. So in your case that would be around `$row['english']`. I also strongly advise you read up on your HTML skills.

Comment: Hi Brat, when I use this print "<PRE>" . $row['english'] . "</PRE>"; it displays fine everything but it is destroying the withd of the website, with other words the text doesn't want to go into a new line once the space is finished, any idea of a resolution ?

Comment: @user981220, what do you want: keep the formatting, or not keep the formatting? You cannot have both. If you only want to keep newlines, use the `nl2br()` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:
http://www.kavoir.com/2009/06/mysql-php-store-form-textarea-value-to-mysql-database-table.html

Just use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: can you show me the input procedure how it will be structured with the mysql_real_escape_string, the actual code if it is ot a problem for you. thanks.

Comment: $data = mysql_real_escape_string[$data];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `authors` (`bio`) VALUES ('$data')");